# Bootstrap estilos dropdowns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy agregando a mi sitio web unos Bootstrap nav, especificamente un Dropdown pero con la version bootstrap 3.3.7 me aparecia todo raro sin estilo el Dropdown.

Luego me fui a la documentacion de bootstrap y encontre la version 4.0.0 que me carga perfectamente los dropdowns sin embargo, toda mi demas pagina esta con:

Letras enormes en donde no deberian haberlos.
Algunos elementos como TABLES e INPUTS incrementaron su tama?o y a pesar de que son responsives, la informacion se mira desordenada.

Hay alguna forma o version de bootstrap en la que me funcione y se vea bien los dropdowns y el resto de estilo sea aceptable?

CDN ACTUAL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

CDN ANTERIOR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

con la version 3.3.7 de bootstrap se mira asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la version 4.0.0 se mira asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la estructura de mis paginas es la siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once 'header.php';

//Body de la pagina

requiere_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

El HEADER.PHP

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title></title>  

           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

                   <!-- CSS -->
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

</head>  
      <body>
```

EL FOOTER.PHP

```
 </body>

 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Y el codigo que contiene mis DROPDOWNS es:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Prestamos</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="clientssession.php">Estado de Prestamo</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="clientssession_paymentshistory.php">Historial de pagos</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Informacion General</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ahorros</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="clientssession_ahorros.php">Estado de Ahorros</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Historial de Abonos y Retiros</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ¿alguna captura de pantalla donde se puedan ver las diferencias? y algo de código de alguna parte afectada.

Comment: Le atribuyo a la forma en la que los usas, pero por si las dudas, la mejor manera para comprobarlo sería copiar el ejemplo de los nav de la documentación de cada versión de bootstrap, tal como está.

Comment: También sería de mucha ayuda que además de las capturas de pantalla que piden también subas codigo.

Comment: ahorita edito la pregunta :) Gracias por su tiempo Shaz & Victor Hugo Tirado

Comment: Sólo como opinión: ¿Porqué cambiar de versión si únicamente necesitas usar los `dropdowns`? Puedes copiar las clases relacionadas de la v4 a la v3.

Comment: Jheyman Mejia, gracias por tu comentario, arriba lo explico que con la version 3.3.7 y 3.3.4 todo se mira bien excepto los dropdowns,  y con la version 4.0.0 los dropdowns se miran bien pero todo lo demas no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien es el mismo framework, hicieron varios cambios entre la versión 3.3* y la versión 4, el código html que debería de funcionar para el dropdown que quieres en las versiones 3.3.*, es el siguiente:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">    
<li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviamente cuando cambiaste de la versión 3.3 a la versión 4 muchos de tus estilos de otros elementos se vieron afectados ya que como menciono, varias cosas cambiaron de una versión a otra.

Para la versión 3.3.* puedes tomar como referencia la siguiente [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components)

Para la versión 4, considera la siguiente [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/)

Answer (score 1):

Depende mucho la versión del bootstrap que uses por ejemplo a mi siempre me ha funcionado de la siguiente forma

```
 <!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

podrías revisar esta documentación 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-static-top/